# postgres: select max returns 9 instead of 10

Tags: postgresql

This is my script:

```
SELECT MAX(distinct TRIM(value, 'SAMPLE_VALUES_'))
FROM sample
WHERE id = 79;
```

My data is somehow like this:

```
id | value
-------------------
79 | SAMPLE_VALUES_6
79 | SAMPLE_VALUES_7
79 | SAMPLE_VALUES_7
79 | SAMPLE_VALUES_8
79 | SAMPLE_VALUES_8
79 | SAMPLE_VALUES_8
79 | SAMPLE_VALUES_9
79 | SAMPLE_VALUES_9
79 | SAMPLE_VALUES_10
79 | SAMPLE_VALUES_10
79 | SAMPLE_VALUES_10
```

But it always returning 9.

Is there something wrong with my script? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast into integer.

```
SELECT MAX(distinct cast(TRIM(value, 'SAMPLE_VALUES_') as integer))
FROM sample
WHERE id = 79
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying the casting maybe i got the wrong syntax earlier.

Comment: Also: watch out for the trim! From what you wrote I think you don't understand what it does. The string provided in the second argument is not trimmed as a whole string, but as list of letters that will be removed. Consider: 

select TRIM('SAMPLE_VALUES_SVLV4837', 'SAMPLE_VALUES_');
select TRIM('SAMPLE_VALUES_SVLV4837', 'SAMPLEVUS_');

Comment: I don't understand why `distinct` is used in the query. OP needs to retun 10 and for this task there is no need for `distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the trimmed result to an integer

```
SELECT MAX(distinct TRIM(value, 'SAMPLE_VALUES_')::int)
FROM sample
WHERE id = 79;
```

Your current query is calling MAX(text) rather than MAX(integer). The rules for comparing text strings is different to comparing numbers - strings are compared character by character, and the first character of '9' is > the first character of '10'.

Comment: Thanks for the information! I thought that max can do that in strings.